# "Bad Storage property" error on LINQ to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I just added a newly created SP to my project which unfortunately required a temp table to operate, so I had to build my RESULT class for the SP manually.  Now when I try to run I get a "Bad Storage Property" error on the below property.

```
public partial class sp_One_EVA_Get_User_InformationResult
{
    private string _Security_USER_ID;

public sp_One_EVA_Get_User_InformationResult()
    {
    }

    [Column(Storage = "_Security_USER_ID;", DbType="VarChar(15) NOT NULL")]
    public string Security_USER_ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Security_USER_ID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Security_USER_ID != value))
            {
                this._Security_USER_ID = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure what is wrong with this, I have done this numerous times with other SP without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this line

`[Column(Storage = "_Security_USER_ID", DbType="VarChar(15) NOT NULL")]`

you have write Storage with error , whith semicolon

Answer (score 1):

It may be this line that is in error:

```
[Column(Storage = "_Security_USER_ID;", DbType="VarChar(15) NOT NULL")]
```

I would double check the `DbType` of the attribute (`VarChar(15) NOT NULL`) against what is actually being returned from the database.  Most likely there is a mismatch between the two.